# Can you override a function from a class outside of a class in Python

Tags: python, function, class, overriding

Can you override a function from a class, like:

```
class A:
    def func():
        print("Out of A")


classA = A

# Is something like this possible
def classA.func():
    print("Overrided!")
```

Wanted Output:
Overrided

I googled "python override function", "python override function from class" and so on but couldnt find anything that fits. I found just how to override the parent function.

Comment: No we can't do this like you mentioned, but there are different ways to override.

Comment: `classA` and `A` are the same object, so if it worked, what you did would override `A.func` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely **shouldn't do this**. If you want to change a single part of some class, make a new class that inherits from it and reimplement the parts you want changed:

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def func():
        print("Out of A")

classA = A

class B(A):
    @staticmethod
    def func():
        print("Overridden!")

A.func()
B.func()
```